# Is there any way to push a commit without a ref?

Tags: git

Is there any way to push a git commit to a repository without modifying any refs on the remote repository? Or does it have to be attached to a ref?

Comment: I'm unclear as to what your requirements are for this.  Do you want to push a commit without any prior history?  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: OP needs to clarify what "ref" refers to. Branch?

Comment: If nothing in the remote refers to the new commit, it could be garbage collected as this is how non-referred to commits are normally handled. **Why would you want to do this** even if it could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no: push (or fetch, for that matter) consists of two parts, one being the transfer of objects, and the other being the adjustment of some name(s) on whichever side received those objects.

The fetch process does not require using any receiver-side `refs/*` references because `git fetch` drops the sender's names (generally, sender-side references) and the hash IDs into `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.  The push process, however, *does* require updating some receiver-side reference, otherwise the newly transferred objects are simply dropped.

(Besides all of this, the choice of objects to transfer usually goes through references as well—though for `git push`, the sender needs only a hash ID.  Fetch, where the receiver is also the initiator of the transfer, *can* work with just a hash ID, provided the sender allows using hash IDs in "want" requests.)